# Allow Users To View Formula Bar If Worksheet protected

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, protected

Sometimes ago I faced with the following problem:
I have protected Worksheets and formulas in cells. So, I haven't opportunity to view formulas in formulas Bar(with lighting).
Thereby, does it really to allow users view formulas in formulas bar if Worksheet protected.

Comment: You can view the formula but you cannot select it if the cell is locked and worksheet protected...

Answer (score 0):

Two conditions are required:

1. When formatting the cells leave the `Hidden` property uncheck in the *Protection* tab (see fig. 1)

[image]

2. When protecting the worksheet check the `Select locked cells` property (see fig. 2)

[image]